# Pinch zoom in vue js

Tags: vue.js, pinchzoom, pinch

I used this [plugin](https://github.com/tolpit/vue-pinch-image) to implement pinch zoom. Image is able to show up, but it seems **the plugin is not working.**

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <PinchImage :src="testImg" :min-zoom="1" :max-zoom="2.5"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PinchImage from './components/PinchImage'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      testImg : 'https://assets.pernod-ricard.com/nz/media_images/test.jpg?hUV74FvXQrWUBk1P2.fBvzoBUmjZ1wct'
    }
  },
  components: {
    PinchImage
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 500px; <----
  height: 500px; <---
}
</style>
```

PinchImage.vue

```
<template>
    <div
            class="pinch-wrapper"
            :style="zoomStyles"
            @touchstart="start"
            @touchmove="move"
            @touchend="end"
    >
        <img :src="src" :alt="alt" class="pinch-img" ref="image"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/babel">

  const DBCLICK_TIME = 200;

  export default {

    props: {
      src: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      alt: String,
      minZoom: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
      },
      maxZoom: {
        type: Number,
        default: 2.25
      }
    },

    data() {
      return {
        zoom: 1,
        minZoomBounce: .015,
        maxZoomBounce: .015,
        speed: .5,
        lastX: null,
        lastY: null,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        zoomCenter: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        },
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,

        lastTouchTime: null,
        clickTimer: null,
        inMovement: false,

        transition: {
          transform: null,
          origin: "transform-origin 400ms linear"
        }
      }
    },

    computed: {
      zoomStyles() {
        let transition = '';

        if(this.transition.transform) transition += this.transition.transform;
        if(this.transition.origin) transition += (transition.length > 0 ? ', ' : '') + this.transition.origin;

        return {
          transform: `scale(${this.zoom}) translate3d(${this.x}px, ${this.y}px, 0px)`,
          transformOrigin: `${this.zoomCenter.x}px ${this.zoomCenter.y}px 0px`,
          transition
        }
      }
    },

    methods: {

      start(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        if(event.touches.length === 2) {
          this.handlePinchStart(event);
        }
        else if(event.touches.length === 1) {
          this.handleTapStart(event);
        }
      },

      end(event) {


        event.preventDefault();

        if(!this.inMovement && this.zoom <= this.minZoom) {
          const timeDiff = event.timeStamp - this.lastTouchTime;

          if(timeDiff > DBCLICK_TIME) {
            this.resetZoom();
          }
        }
        else {
          this.lastX = 0;
          this.lastY = 0;
        }

        if(event.touches.length === 0) {
          if(this.zoom <= 1) {
            this.lastTouchTime = event.timeStamp;
          }
        }
      },

      move(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        if(event.touches.length === 2) {
          this.handlePinchMove(event);
        }
        else {
          this.handlePanMove(event);
        }
      },

      resetZoom() {
        console.log('reset');

        //this.transition.transform = "transform 200ms linear";

        this.zoom = 1;
        this.zoomCenter.x = 0;
        this.zoomCenter.y = 0;
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.transition.transform = null;
        }, 200);
      },

      handlePinchStart(event) {
        const {x,y} = this.getTouchCenter(
          this.getTouchesCenter(event.touches[0], event.touches[1])
        );

        if(this.zoom < this.maxZoom) {
          this.zoomCenter.x = x;
          this.zoomCenter.y = y;
        }

        this.lastDistance = this.getZoomDistance(event.touches[0], event.touches[1]);
      },

      handlePinchMove(event) {
        const zoom  = this.getZoomDistance(event.touches[0], event.touches[1]);
        const last  = (zoom / this.lastDistance);
        const scale = this.calcZoom(this.minZoom - this.minZoomBounce, this.maxZoom + this.maxZoomBounce, this.zoom * last);

        if(this.zoom < this.maxZoom || (this.zoom >= this.maxZoom && scale < this.zoom)) {
          this.zoom = scale;
        }

        this.lastDistance = zoom;
      },

      handlePanMove(event) {
        if(this.zoom > 1) {
          const touch = event.touches[0];
          const x = touch.clientX;
          const y = touch.clientY;

          if (!this.lastX || !this.lastY) {
            this.lastX = x;
            this.lastY = y;

            return null;
          }
          else {
            const rect = this.$refs.image.getBoundingClientRect();

            let diffX = (x - this.lastX) * this.speed;
            let diffY = (y - this.lastY) * this.speed;

            this.transition.transform = null;

            //apply transform
            this.x += diffX;
            this.y += diffY;

            //bounds
            if(rect.left > 0 && diffX > 0) {
              this.x -= diffX;
            }
            if(rect.right < this.width && diffX < 0) {
              this.x -= diffX;
            }
            if(rect.top > 0 && diffY > 0) {
              this.y -= diffY;
            }
            if(rect.bottom < this.height && diffY < 0) {
              this.y -= diffY;
            }

            //to calc the next move
            this.lastX = x;
            this.lastY = y;
          }
        }
      },

      handleTapStart(event) {
        const touch = event.touches[0];
        const x = touch.clientX;
        const y = touch.clientY;

        if(!this.lastX || !this.lastY) {
          this.lastX = x;
          this.lastY = y;
        }

        if(this.lastTouchTime) {
          const timeDiff = event.timeStamp - this.lastTouchTime;

          if(timeDiff < DBCLICK_TIME) {
            this.handleDoubleTap(event.touches[0]);

            this.lastX = null;
            this.lastY = null;
          }
        }

        this.lastTouchTime = event.timeStamp;
      },

      handleDoubleTap(touch) {
        let {x,y} = this.getTouchCenter({ x:touch.clientX, y: touch.clientY });

        clearTimeout(this.clickTimeout);

        this.inMovement = true;
        this.transition.origin    = "transform-origin 400ms linear";
        this.transition.transform = "transform 200ms linear";

        if(this.zoom > this.minZoom) {
          this.zoom = 1;
          this.x = 0;
          this.y = 0;

          this.clickTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.zoomCenter.x = 0;
            this.zoomCenter.y = 0;

            this.inMovement = false;
          }, 200);
        }
        else {
          this.transition.origin = null;

          this.zoomCenter.x = x;
          this.zoomCenter.y = y;

          this.clickTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.transition.origin = "transform-origin 400ms linear";
            this.zoom              = this.maxZoom;

            this.inMovement = false;
          }, 200);
        }
      },

      getTouchCenter({x, y}) {
        const rect = this.$el.getBoundingClientRect();

        return {
          x: x - rect.left,
          y: y - rect.top
        }
      },

      calcZoom(e, t, n) {
        return Math.min(t, Math.max(e, n))
      },

      getZoomDistance(e, t) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e.clientY - t.clientY, 2) + Math.pow(e.clientX - t.clientX, 2));
      },

      getTouchesCenter(touch1, touch2) {
        return {
          x: (touch1.clientX + touch2.clientX) / 2,
          y: (touch1.clientY + touch2.clientY) / 2
        }
      },

      bounds() {
        const rect = this.$refs.image.getBoundingClientRect();

        console.log(rect);
        console.log({x:this.x,y:this.y,zoom:this.zoom});

        if(rect.left < 0) {
          this.x = 0;
        }
        else if(rect.right > this.width) {
          this.x = 0;
        }
        if(rect.top < 0) {
          this.y = 0;
        }
        else if(rect.bottom > this.height) {
          this.y = 0;
        }

        console.log({x:this.x,y:this.y});
      }

    }

  }
</script>

<style lang="css">
    .pinch-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

        align-items: stretch;
        border-width: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        flex-basis: auto;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: inherit;
        font: inherit;
        text-align: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        min-height: 0;
        min-width: 0;
    }
    .pinch-wrapper:hover {
        will-change: transform;
    }
    .pinch-img {
        position: absolute;
        width: auto !important;
        height: auto !important;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        object-position: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
```

[Full code here](https://github.com/kenpeter/pinch-image)

Comment: Give your `#app` a height.

Comment: @StevenB. ok, I give the #app height width 500px. It seems the plugin is not able to pinch zoom i.e. not doing anything

Comment: Sounds like an issue for the plugin author.

Comment: @StevenB. yes it is.